# Why for DDR3 driver with a low-impedance output undesirable?

Tags: layout, impedance-matching, termination, ddr3, dram

I was reading Micron's [TN-41-13 DDR3 Point-to-Point Design Support](https://www.micron.com/-/media/client/global/documents/products/technical-note/dram/tn4113_ddr3_point_to_point_design.pdf) technical note. It says the following on page 7:

> In point-to-point designs, the memory’s position is typically quite close to the controller, which results in short data bus trace lengths. This makes a driver with a low-impedance output undesirable.

What I know is Output impedance should be low and input impedance should be high. How is this undesirable in this context?

Comment: I think it's a bad use of language in the linked article. You do want an output impedance that is close to a standard impedance such as 50 ohms and, the lower you go below that the more the likelihood that you'll get progressive reflections causing corruptions of data. It's less of a problem with shorter trace lengths hence, the article words are somewhat confusing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What made the lower impedance undesireable for DDR-3 was the lower eye-margin from the wider tolerances of DDR2 and the great power consumption.

For a given slew rate and fixed threshold, different impedance mismatch causes jitter from eye pattern reduction.  So they needed a ways to match impedances for R/W DDR3 with tighter tolerances and a higher impedance was chosen yet still in the 50 Ohm range.  Calibration and multiple gate selected pullups were used to tune the pullup.

So for high speed memory you want low impedance for both output and inputs to be matched to something like 10% rather than have a driver much lower than the RAM as it was in DDR2.

[ref](https://www.micron.com/-/media/client/global/documents/products/technical-note/dram/tn4113_ddr3_point_to_point_design.pdf)